Timm throwing HuggingFace Hub not installed error when HFhub is installed
I'm trying to create the convit_base.fb_in1k model via timm. When I call timm.create_model('convit_base.fb_in1k', pretrained=True), I get a RuntimeError: Hugging Face hub model specified but package not installed. Run 'pip install huggingface_hub'. error. I have huggingface_hub installed.
There seem to be various suggestions around the web to update other packages, all of which I have updated. I'm running python 3.8 with huggingface-hub==0.22.2, timm==0.9.16, tokenizers==0.15.2, transformers==4.39.3, safetensors==0.4.3, torch==2.2.2, torchvision==0.17.2. The full pip freeze list can be found here.
I'm not sure how to fix this error.

which version of huggingface_hub do you have installed? Can you share pip list?

@Ivan - huggingface_hub==0.22.2. I shared what I thought were the relevant packages in the question, but I will attach a document with the full pip list

import sys; print(sys.executable), use that output, e.g. /usr/lib/python and then to /usr/lib/python -m pip install transformers
